# Explain how recursion works in an algorithm to determine depth of binary tree?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion, binary-tree, depth

I am new to data structures in JavaScript and am trying to learn Binary Search Trees.  I was following along with a blog post and was able to get a working solution to the problem of finding the max depth in a BST, but it's unclear to me how the recursion is working and how the +1 gets added on each time at each level of depth. What is a good way to think about this? Is it basically that each time the nodes value is not null, 1 gets added to what will eventually be returned up the call stack (i.e. at each level as it backtracks up to the root)?

```
 function maxDepth(node) {
  // console.log(node.left);
  if (node) {
    return Math.max(maxDepth(node.left), maxDepth(node.right)) + 1;
  } else {

    return 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: The top half of your question, with the `maxDepth()` function, is enough scope for us to answer. You can delete the second block of code.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The code for `maxDepth(node)` reads like this:

1. If `node` is not `null`:

   1. Run this same algorithm `maxDepth` on `node`'s left child. Let this answer be `x`.
   2. Run this same algorithm `maxDepth` on `node`'s right child. Let this answer be `y`.
   3. Calculate `Math.max(x, y) + 1`, and return this value as the answer for this function call.
2. Otherwise `node` is `null`, then return `0`.

---

This means when we try to compute `maxDepth(node)` on a non-null node, we first compute `maxDepth()` on both of `node`'s children, and let those two subcomputations finish. Then we take the maximum of these values, add 1, and return the result.

**Example:**

```
      a
     / \
    b   f
   / \   \
  c   e   g
 /           
d
```

Call stack:

```
a => max(b,f)
b => max(c,e)
c => max(d,null)
d => max(null,null)
d <= (0,0)+1 = 1
c <= (1,0)+1 = 2
e => max(null,null)
e <= (0,0)+1 = 1
b <= (2,1)+1 = 3
f => (null,g)
g => (null,null)
g <= (0,0)+1 = 1
f <= (0,1)+1 = 2
a <= (3,2)+1 = 4
```

Answer (score 6):

Let me rewrite the code in a little simpler way for the sake of an easy and better explanation.

```
function maxDepth(node) {
  if (node == null)
      return 0;
  else {
      l = maxDepth(node.left)
      r = maxDepth(node.right)
      return Math.max(left, right) + 1;
  }
}
```

Now, let's explain the above recursion with the following tree:

```
      A
     / \
    B   C
   /    
  D
```

The function `maxDepth(node)` get called with the root (`A`), therefore, we will explain our recursion stack pictorially starting from node `A`:

```
A
| l = ?
|-------> B
|         | l = ?
|         |-------> D
|         |         | l = ?
|         |         |-------> null (return 0)

A
| l = ?
|-------> B
|         | l = ?
|         |-------> D
|         |         | l = 0 <---------|
|         |         |-------> null (return 0)

A
| l = ?
|-------> B
|         | l = ?
|         |-------> D
|         |         | l = 0 
|         |         |
|         |         | r = ?
|         |         |-------> null (return 0)

A
| l = ?
|-------> B
|         | l = ?
|         |-------> D
|         |         | l = 0 
|         |         |
|         |         | r = 0 <---------|
|         |         |-------> null (return 0)

A
| l = ?
|-------> B
|         | l = ? <--------------------------|
|         |-------> D                        |
|         |         | l = 0                  |
|         |         |          max(0,0)+1 => 1
|         |         | r = 0 


A
| l = ?
|-------> B
|         | l = 1 <--------------------------|
|         |-------> D                        |
|         |         | l = 0                  |
|         |         |          max(0,0)+1 => 1
|         |         | r = 0 


A
| l = ?
|-------> B
|         | l = 1 
|         |
|         | r = ? 
|         | -------> null (return 0)

A
| l = ?
|-------> B
|         | l = 1 
|         |
|         | r = 0 <---------| 
|         | -------> null (return 0)


A
| l = ? <--------------------------|
|-------> B                        |
|         | l = 1                  | 
|         |          max(1,0)+1 => 2
|         | r = 0

A
| l = 2 <--------------------------|
|-------> B                        |
|         | l = 1                  | 
|         |          max(1,0)+1 => 2
|         | r = 0

A
| l = 2 
|
| r = ?        
| -------> C 
|          | l = ? <---------| 
|          |-------> null (return 0)

A
| l = 2 
|
| r = ?        
| -------> C 
|          | l = 0 
|          |
|          | r = ? <---------| 
|          |-------> null (return 0)

A
| l = 2 
|
| r = ? <---------------------------|        
| -------> C                        | 
|          | l = 0                  | 
|          |          max(0,0)+1 => 1
|          | r = 0 

A
| l = 2 
|
| r = 1 <---------------------------|        
| -------> C                        | 
|          | l = 0                  | 
|          |          max(0,0)+1 => 1
|          | r = 0 


A <----------------------|  
| l = 2                  |  
|          max(2,1)+1 => 3
| r = 1
```

Finally, `A` returns `3`.

```
3
^
|
A (3)<-------------------|  
| l = 2                  |  
|          max(2,1)+1 => 3
| r = 1
```